# Flutter: database is locked Possibly there are two concurrent builds running in the same filesystem location

Tags: xcode, flutter

Trying to run the app on my two iOS devices by doing `flutter run -d all`. However, I am getting `database is locked Possibly there are two concurrent builds running in the same filesystem location.` error.

**What have I tried**

- `flutter clean`
- `flutter run` separately
- running the app on iPad on the terminal & on iPhone on xCode works

So, it looks like I am having a problem to run Flutter app on my two iOS devices at the same time.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: having exact same problem, would love to know how to resolve. NB:Multiple android devices run without a hitch. [Flutter 2.10.3; VS Code 1.65.2 (Mac)]

Comment: have you found the solution? It looks like it is a problem of xcode. But couldn't make it work at the moemtn :/

Comment: @chichi, Can you please share the step to reproduce it or share the sample code where I can reproduce the scenario.

Comment: What is the output of flutter doctor?

Comment: flutter doctor comes clean. Everything is checked

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have MacBook Pro M1, and I solved this problem as follows:

I tried flutter create --projectname... etc and it did not work (you can see above this answer). I also glanced all of the topics, but they also did not work. So, you need to do these steps:

before doing these steps, in the terminal:

pod install

pod repo update

then:

1 - delete `Podfile.lock` file

2 - `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi` **in the root of the file**

3 - `cd ios`

4 - `arch -x86_64 pod install`  **here, you must do this step in the ios folder**

If it's works for your project as well, then you can give an upvote for people who are faced with a problem. Thanks

Comment: did not work for my m1 pro

Comment: it works @CasparBm, you may need to have another problem from Xcode...

Answer (score 16):

Just remove DerivedData

`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/XCode/DerivedData`

Path will be shown in error which you get in console.

and then rebuilt it

Comment: If you are using `-derivedDataPath Build/` as part of `xcodebuild` removing `Build` folder would make it right

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this article](https://phongyewtong.medium.com/how-to-fix-flutter-xcode-error-database-is-locked-possibly-there-are-two-concurrent-builds-22de1266dc0d), just issuing a

```
flutter clean
```

in the project directory solved the problem for me. The build worked fine then.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

What worked for me was to simply follow the hint from @NDeveloper (https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/691359?login=true). Just delete and readd my iOS emulator from the device management in Xcode.

Comment: worked on same problem with capacitor

Answer (score 0):

You can run the app in the release mod by using flutter run --release on multiple ios devices. Tested and worked inside the android studio.

Comment: will try when i get back mate!

Answer (score -9):

This solution has worked for me, so try this:

1. Remove the IOS folder in the project
2. Run "flutter create --project-name={YOUR_PROJECT_NAME} ." command in the terminal on the root path of the project
3. Run "flutter run" command or while main.dart selected start debugging